# If org-agenda-mode, substitute "Args out of range: 0, 0" for a prettier message

Tags: emacs, elisp

I understand that the error message means there are no todo entries that mach the search criteria:

```
org-agenda-find-same-or-today-or-agenda: Args out of range: 0, 0
```

Is there any way to generate a prettier message instead:

```
(if (and (eq major-mode 'org-agenda-mode)
      (org-agenda-find-same-or-today-or-agenda: Args out of range: 0, 0) )
  (message "There are no events that match your search criteria."))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `condition-case` to handle that standard error:

```
 (if (and (eq major-mode 'org-agenda-mode)
          (condition-case err
              (org-agenda-find-same-or-today-or-agenda ...) ; Whatever args you need to pass.
            (args-out-of-range (error "There are no events that match your search criteria"))
            (error (error (error-message-string err)))))
     ...)
```

However, it sounds like you should correct the code so that that error is prevented, instead. Can't you test the argument(s) to `org-agenda-find-same-or-today-or-agenda` before you call it, and call it only if the argument(s) is/are valid?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense -- i.e., looking in the chain of commands to the one leading up to `org-agenda-find-same-or-today-or-agenda`.  That entire function essentially is just `(goto-char (point-min))` with a bunch of `or` conditions preceding `(point-min)`.  I'll spend a little more time on the issue tonight, and then pick it up again tomorrow with a cup of coffee.  Thank you for the `condition-case` example -- I was trying something similar with `string=` and had trouble with my format.  Also, `args-out-of-range` didn't come up with describe function or describe variable . . .

Comment: See the Elisp manual, node `Standard Errors`, for a list of standard errors.

Comment: Thank you -- I modified the underlying function `org-agenda-change-time-span`, which calls `org-agenda-find-same-or-today-or-agenda`.